# Override HTML id using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following declaration:

```
<header id="page-header" class="head">
```

How do I override the id 'page-header' to any other name using css?

Comment: You can't do that. ID rules have more priority than any CSS-only class. You need to add at least #page-header to the new rule to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Not css but easily done with JS

You simply make a reference to the element `let header = document.getElementById("page-header");`, remove the id attribute `header.removeAttribute("id");` and add a new id attribute `header.setAttribute("id", "newId");`

Working snippet:

```js
let header = document.getElementById("page-header");
console.log(header.id);

header.removeAttribute("id");
console.log(header.id);

header.setAttribute("id", "newId");

console.log(header.id);
```

```html
<header id="page-header" class="head">
```